# IBM Cognos Report Studio Error: RQP-DEF-0191;Column names must be unique

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

#### Error: **"rqp-def-0149 the query specification is incorrect. RQP-DEF-0191;Column names must be unique. Column name 'Attribute_Name' is used more."**

The above said error has occured when trying to run a report in cognos. The error is not occurring for all the run, but rarely it occures. The attribute is used in summary filter as ( *Attribute_name IN ?prompt_input_values?* ). This attribute is used as a multiselect prompt in Prompt page. And the attribute is also used as a data item in the query.

Can anyone pls explain why this error occurs?

Your replies are appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a Detail Filter than a Summary Filter. In addition, use the full notation - [Namespace].[Query Subject].[Data Item]